# No longer able to filter by parameters in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, 2016, data-view-web-part

I am attempting to filter a list by a begin date and and end date using the date filter web parts. Up until about a month ago, I could create a Site Page containing 2 date filter web parts
(FromDate and ToDate) and a list web part below. I'd check the page out and edit in Advanced mode with SharePoint Designer 2013.  To view the necessary tools for parameters and filters in the ribbon, I'd click the XsltListViewWebPart and choose tag properties and without making any change I would click OK and then click on the XsltListViewWebPart again to reveal the tools in the ribbon.  Now, when I do this, I get this message:

The file you imported is not valid. Verify that the file is a Web Part description file
(*.webpart or *.dwp) and that it contains well-formed XML.

This pertains to SharePoint 2016 Enterprise and Designer 2013. I have tried clicking choices under Miscellaneous and also Server Render, but the message remains and I cannot reveal the tools in the ribbon. Any ideas? I tried this in a development instance and the same thing occurs. I am stuck and unable to edit previously created pages using parameters.

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you working with? On-prem or Online?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2016 On Premise. Sorry, I should've added that.